# Stormcrawler pages with noindex nofollow are crawled

Tags: stormcrawler

We are using Stormcrawler 1.13 to crawl site pages. When using in one environment, it's not crawling pages having robots meta noindex nofollow but when we are deploying the same modules in another environment, pages with noindex nofollow are also crawled. Below is our crawler-conf.yaml.

```
# Custom configuration for StormCrawler
# This is used to override the default values from crawler-default.xml and provide additional ones 
# for your custom components.
# Use this file with the parameter -conf when launching your extension of ConfigurableTopology.
# This file does not contain all the key values but only the most frequently used ones. See crawler-default.xml for an extensive list.

config: 
  topology.workers: 1
  topology.message.timeout.secs: 300
  topology.max.spout.pending: 100
  topology.debug: false

  fetcher.threads.number: 50
  
  # give 2gb to the workers
  worker.heap.memory.mb: 2048

  # mandatory when using Flux
  topology.kryo.register:
    - com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Metadata

  # metadata to transfer to the outlinks
  # used by Fetcher for redirections, sitemapparser, etc...
  # these are also persisted for the parent document (see below)
  # metadata.transfer:
  # - customMetadataName

  # lists the metadata to persist to storage
  # these are not transfered to the outlinks
  metadata.persist:
   - _redirTo
   - error.cause
   - error.source
   - isSitemap
   - isFeed

  http.agent.name: "Anonymous Coward"
  http.agent.version: "1.0"
  http.agent.description: "built with StormCrawler Archetype ${version}"
  http.agent.url: "http://someorganization.com/"
  http.agent.email: "someone@someorganization.com"

  # The maximum number of bytes for returned HTTP response bodies.
  # The fetched page will be trimmed to 65KB in this case
  # Set -1 to disable the limit.
  http.content.limit: -1

  # FetcherBolt queue dump => comment out to activate
  # if a file exists on the worker machine with the corresponding port number
  # the FetcherBolt will log the content of its internal queues to the logs
  # fetcherbolt.queue.debug.filepath: "/tmp/fetcher-dump-{port}"

  parsefilters.config.file: "parsefilters.json"
  urlfilters.config.file: "urlfilters.json"

  # revisit a page daily (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.default: 1440

  # revisit a page with a fetch error after 2 hours (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.fetch.error: 120

  # never revisit a page with an error (or set a value in minutes)
  fetchInterval.error: -1

  # custom fetch interval to be used when a document has the key/value in its metadata
  # and has been fetched successfully (value in minutes)
  # fetchInterval.FETCH_ERROR.isFeed=true: 30
  # fetchInterval.isFeed=true: 10

  # configuration for the classes extending AbstractIndexerBolt
  # indexer.md.filter: "someKey=aValue"
  indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
  indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
  - domain=domain

  # Metrics consumers:
  topology.metrics.consumer.register:
     - class: "org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
       parallelism.hint: 1
```

Please let me know if need to do some changes in above code or any other configurations in storm-crawler.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of meta noindex is not configurable in 1.13 so any difference between your environments can't be due to a difference in configuration.

How did you generate the topology? Did you use the archetype?

PS: it is good practice to set the *http.agent.** configs.

Comment: Hi @Julien nioche. Thanks for quick reply. We used mvn generate:artchetype command to generate module. We are using "storm jar storm-crawler-1.13.jar org.apache.storm.flux.Flux es-crawler.flux --remote" to add topology in Storm and storm-crawler-1.13.jar is having auto generated CrawlTopology class which extends ConfigurableTopology. Please suggest what might be the issue. Thank you very much